# Rails 4 many to many relationship

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have an app that has 2 models that need a many to many relationship. I originally tried using has_and_belongs_to_many but it wasn't working. After scrummaging through the internet I was convinced that this was not what I needed anyhow. So, I switched to a has_many through method. However, this isn't working either. I am now at a major loss on what the issue is. I have ripped it out many times and tried tutorial after tutorial but to no avail.

The models I am trying to connect are Message and Author. In my most recent attempt, I created a joining model (with corresponding table) called Authoring. Here is my code:

message.rb

```
    has_many :authorings
    has_many :authors, through: :authorings
```

author.rb

```
    has_many :authorings
    has_many :messages, through: :authorings
```

authoring.rb

```
    belongs_to :message
    belongs_to :author
```

messages_controller.rb

```
    def messages_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:title, :summary, :date, :duration, :youversion, :hours, :minutes, :seconds, :authors)
    end
```

My Messages form:

```
    <%= f.label :speakers %><br /> 
    <%= collection_select(:authors, :authors, Author.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 10}) %>
```

When I created a new message, this showed in the log:

```
     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"OcLeke/eRRzwApoMSgQF81kBCm7TaGxW1PoVAUgEcvo=", "message"=>{"title"=>"Test1", "summary"=>"This is my test summary.", "date(2i)"=>"8", "date(3i)"=>"25", "date(1i)"=>"2014", "date(4i)"=>"01", "date(5i)"=>"00", "hours"=>"0", "minutes"=>"58", "seconds"=>"52", "youversion"=>""}, "authors"=>{"authors"=>["", "1"]}, "commit"=>"I'm Finished", "id"=>"1"}
```

The form obviously recognizes the authors in the form but it doesn't save them in the database. What is my disconnect? Please help!!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authors` records are not getting created because the controller is expecting *`authors` to be present within `message` key's value* in `params` hash BUT if you notice the `params` hash in the log

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
>   "authenticity_token"=>"OcLeke/eRRzwApoMSgQF81kBCm7TaGxW1PoVAUgEcvo=", 
>   "message"=>{...},  "authors"=>{...},  "commit"=>"I'm Finished", 
>   "id"=>"1"}

you would see that `authors` is coming as an altogether separate key in `params` hash which is why it is being ignored.

What you need to do is associate the authors with the `form` object, instead of using `collection_select` you need to use `f.collection_select` as shown below. Specify the first argument as `:author_ids` in `f.collection_select`.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:author_ids, Author.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 10}) %>
```

As you have `:multiple => true` option specified, you would receive `authors` as an `Array` in the `params` hash. You need to permit `author_ids` as an `Array` in `message_params` method

```
def messages_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:title, :summary, :date, :duration, :youversion, :hours, :minutes, :seconds, :author_ids => [])
end
```